# Change in focal length of lens inside water

Tags: lenses

I read it on Yahoo Answers (link below) that the power of lens changes when the lens is placed inside water. But then, if we consider the formula f=c/2 , the radius if curvature of the lens still remains same, then, how can the focal length change?

While considering the definition (point where light rays meet) we see that the focal length changes.
But while considering the formula (f=c/2) focal length doesn't change.

Can anyone please explain this and please do mention whether the focal length actually changes or not.

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090217024946AAk1njB

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eyes open under water](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4010/eyes-open-under-water)

Comment: No the answer isn't there in those answers. :)

Comment: Because the curvature of the lens is not the only aspect determining the focal length. The materials of lens and surroundings need also be taken into account. Which is done in the yahoo reference as in the reference given by DumpsterDoofus. And yes it changes

Comment: The lens bends light by *refraction*. Refraction depends on the indicies of refraction on both sides of the boundary. In other words, the accepted answer on @DumpsterDoofus' proposed duplicate contains the heart of the answer in the first sentence.

Comment: @HarshalGajjar: The answer is in there, read it again.

Comment: I know that the focal length changes, it's pretty obvious that the difference in refractive indices will affect the focal length of the lens but then in our school we have been taught that f is half c. Now, if you just think on both the conditions together, then how is f equal to half c!? That's what I am asking.

Comment: @HarshalGajjar: I posted the reason why you can't use $f=c/2$ as an answer below, let me know if it answers your question or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula $$f=\frac{c}{2}$$ where $c$ is the radius of curvature is for *mirrors*, not lenses.

The reason you are getting a wrong result is that you are applying a formula designed for mirrors to a lens.

Incidentally, the formula $f=\frac{c}{2}$ is still valid for mirrors underwater.

Comment: Then is there no relation between C and F of lens? Also, in all my classes, I, used this same relation even for lens and got the correct answer, was that just coincidence? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I don't see how $f=c/2$ could apply to lenses. Where does the index of refraction enter the formula? Also, do you have a reference for the formula? I've searched online, but I've never seen it applied to lenses, only mirrors. Usually the Lensmaker's Equation is used for lenses, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_(optics)#Lensmaker.27s_equation.

Comment: Whenever C was given I used to just divide it by 2 to get the focal length. :) Anyways now I got my mistake, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Air, water and glass have different [refractive indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index). This is a name given to a property of materials that affects the direction of a ray of light crossing a boundary between two materials. It is related to the speed of light in those materials.

[image]

This angle of refraction affects the focal length of a lens.

If you drop a glass lens into a liguid with the same refractive index, the lens no longer focuses light at all.

[image]
<sup>Image from [gr5.org](http://gr5.org/index_of_refraction/)</sup>

Comment: So is the formula f=c/2 wrong?

Comment: As long as you do take in account the refractive indices, yes it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The focal length of a lens changes when the optical medium changes because focal length of any lens depends on the refractive index of the optical medium.